# ssh-copy-id ceph@osd-0 /bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/ceph/.pub': No such file or directory

Tags: ceph

I can ssh successfully my ceph osd nodes but when i am trying to copy ssh id i am getting below error can anyone guide why i am getting below errors.

[ceph@monitor ~]$ ssh-copy-id ceph@osd-0

/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/ceph/.pub': No such file or directory
(to install the contents of '/home/ceph/.pub' anyway, look at the -f option)
[ceph@monitor ~]$

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question, post it as an answer instead and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 1):

your local public key is not found in `/home/ceph/.pub`

By default, your SSH keys are in `/home/user/.ssh/key[.pub]`

You can specify the right key to use with the `-i` (i for 'identity') option :

`ssh-copy-id user@server -i /file/to/use`

Answer (score 0):

95% of keys issues are related to permissions.   Make sure .ssh folder exists and the permissions are .ssh permissions are 700 and all files in folder are 600.  The current user is the owner on all files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).